# How to Assert that a specific Exception is not thrown in NUnit?

Tags: c#, json, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm using NUnit for testing and have a piece of code where I use JObject.Parse(json). I want to ensure that this code does not throw a JsonReaderException. Here is the assertion I've tried:

`Assert.That(() => { JObject.Parse(json); }, Throws.Nothing);`

The above assertion only confirms that no exception is thrown, but I want to specifically assert that a JsonReaderException is not thrown. Is there a way to do this in NUnit?

I've tried using things like `Throws.Not.JsonReaderException`, among other things, but none seem to work. I expected to find an NUnit assertion that allows me to check for the absence of a specific exception, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: I'd consider asserting what you do want the code to do, not what you want it to not do. It makes sense sometimes to assert that your code does throw a specific exception. I'm sure the purpose of the method isn't to *not* throw an exception. If it was you could just delete the body of the method and then it would never throw that exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just negate the constraint with `!`:

```
// Fails:
Assert.That(() => { throw new AggregateException();},
    !Throws.InstanceOf<AggregateException>());

// Passes:
Assert.That(() => { throw new AggregateException();},
    !Throws.InstanceOf<InvalidOperationException>());
```

`Constraint` class has overloaded `!` operator which is somewhat equivalent to creating new `NotConstraint`. For example the following in this case will also work:

```
Assert.That(() => { throw new AggregateException();},
    new NotConstraint(Throws.InstanceOf<InvalidOperationException>()));
```

Note that current implementation of the operator is [a bit more complex](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/9b5ec78f28a00077ef4928f3a62a21a6853283e6/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Constraints/Constraint.cs#L207):

```
public static Constraint operator !(Constraint constraint)
{
    var r = (IResolveConstraint)constraint;
    return new NotConstraint(r.Resolve());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built-in straight forward way to assert a specific exception isn't thrown, but you can always use `try...catch` inside your test method.
Something like this will do the trick:

```
try
{
  JObject.Parse(json);
}
catch(JsonReaderException ex)
{
    // This will make the test fail...
    throw;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // ignore or log or whatever, this is just so that the test will pass.
}
```

This way, any exception that isn't `JsonReaderException` will pass the test, but `JsonReaderException` will not.